# Domain files download upon opening

Tags: php, html

I'm having this weird issue with my Domain. My domain is `saoo.eu` hosted on HostZilla.
The issue is that whenever I open an HTML/PHP file it automatically downloads it instead of opening it into the browser. Example the `saoo.eu/test.html` page. 
Same thing happens with the `index.html` file. What is going on?

Also if I want an PHP code ran into an HTML file I have to add an `.htaccess` file. But it doesn't seem to work. Tested it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is possibly missing this apache mod

> Does your browser ask if you want to download the php file instead of
>   displaying it? If Apache is not actually parsing the php after you
>   restarted it, install libapache2-mod-php5. It is installed when you
>   install the php5 package, but may have been removed inadvertently by
>   packages which need to run a different version of php.
>
> If sudo a2enmod php5 returns "$ This module does not exist!", you
>   should purge (not just remove) the libapache2-mod-php5 package and
>   reinstall it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Definitely something wrong with Apache. Happened to me a while back. Hosting support should be able to fix it quickly.

Comment: Yes definitely contact hosting support. Unless you have root access on your server to check this yourself

Answer (score 0):

You should check the webserver/.htaccess configuration. Ask the hosting support to check it for you.